# C++ Beginner question: Constructor

Tags: c++

I just came across the following source code of an constructor.

```
testProg::testProg() : CCProg()  
{  
m_UID = n_UID = 0;  
}
```

Normally, an constructor looks as follows according to my understanding:

```
testProg::testProg()    
{    
m_UID = n_UID = 0;    
}
```

So I am wondering what is the purpose of this CCProg(), would be great if someone
could quickly tell me what is going on here. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

It would seem that testProg inherits from CCProg, and the no-args constructor for CCProg is being called from the [initialization list](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html) of the testProg constructor.

Given that it is the no-args constructor that is being called, the explicit call isn't actually required (it would be called implicity anyway). Therefore the main use of this syntax would be to call a parent constructor that does take arguments.

For example:

```
testProg::testProg(int days) : CCProg(days)  
{  
m_UID = n_UID = 0;  
}
```

Here, if the explicit call was left out, the no-args constructor would be called implicity if one were available, otherwise compilation would fail.

Note that it is also possible (though far less likely), that CCProg is the name of a member variable belonging to testProg - again, the explicit call to the no-args constructor is not required as it would be called implicity.

Comment: Correct. For the OP's benefit, these are called "constructor initialization lists" in C++ lingo.

Answer (score 6):

It's either an explicit call to the base class constructor, if the class looks like this:

```
class testProg : public CCProg
```

or (less likely) a call to initialise a member variable, if the class looks like this:

```
class testProg
{
    Something CCProg;
    // ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Either:

- class testProg is derived from class
  CCProg, or
- class testProg has an embedded
  object named CCProg

In both cases it is an explicit call to a constructor of CCProg, and because it is a parameter-less constructor that call is allowed but not strictly necessary.

However, if CCProg had a constructor with an int parameter, you would have to call it with something like

```
testProg::testProg() : CCProg(1) { }
```

This syntax allows you to select a constructor (in case CCProg has more than 1) and pass a value. Also note the order in which things happen: CCProg is constructed before the testprog ctor body is entered.

Answer (score 0):

What this code does is that it is calling the constructor of the class CCProg() explicitly.

In an inheritance architecture, to save the effort of rewriting the constructor of the base class again we can use this technique.